# how to use android-support-multidex.jar for phone prior to Android 5.0 in android studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

I want to build my app with more classes.dex file in one apk. So I follow instruction of google help page. It is ok for android 5.0, But i cannot build for phone prior to Android 5.0. it always report:com.android.dex.DexException: Too many classes in --main-dex-list, main dex capacity exceeded. I don't know hot to build. My build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    //buildToolsVersion "20"
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.ccbtest.first"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        tasks.matching {
            it.name.startsWith('dex')
        }.each { dx ->
            if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
                dx.additionalParameters = []
            }
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex' // enable multidex

            // optional
            // dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex list=$projectDir/<filename>".toString() // enable the main-dex-list
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/ccbtest.jar')
    compile files('libs/ccbtest1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ccbtest2.jar')
    compile files('libs/ccbtest3.jar')
    compile files('libs/ccbtest4.jar')
    compile files('libs/ccbtest5.jar')
    compile files('libs/ccbtest6.jar')

    // Multi-dex Lib
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

if i modify minSdkVersion 21 from 21 to 20. It will fail.

I want to in phone prior to android 5.0. Please help me about this.

thanks.

br

mwt

.

Comment: Just make sure you follow all steps outlined [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html). In particular, pay attention to the fact that you *also* need to either make your manifest point to `MultiDexApplication` or call `MultiDex.install(...)` in an already existing app extension.

Comment: HI, HM, Thanks. But i realy don't know the reason that build will fail after modify from minSdkVersion 21 to minSdkVersion 20.

Comment: Basically the reason for this is that dalvik must not be supported. Which causes all the Multidex trouble

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as oberflansch [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753991/how-to-use-android-support-multidex-jar-for-phone-prior-to-android-5-0-in-androi#comment53355615_32754596), remove the closure that you're passing to `afterEvaluate`. The Android gradle plugin will handle all the dx configuration automatically once you've specified `multiDexEnabled = true`.

The `Too many classes in --main-dex-list, main dex capacity exceeded` error most probably says that your ***main dex file*** exceeded the 65536 methods limit.

I have encountered the same issue in the past, and eventually had to patch the Android gradle plugin to not include Activity classes in main dex. It's a bit hacky, but works well. See [my blogpost](http://blog.osom.info/2014/12/too-many-methods-in-main-dex.html) for further explanation.

Comment: HI, Alex, Thank you very much. I was reading your blog. I will try your example project. Thank again. Sorry for respons so lately, i cannot access your blog without tools.

Comment: hi, Alex, after modifing according to your advice, build ok now. Thanks your help firstly. All activity is placed into second dex file now. My test class and methods are put in first and second dex file without any rule. I don't know whether only first dex file have method limitation in this case. Can you explain it? Thanks.

Comment: @mmm2006 Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what exactly are you asking. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Hi, Alex, sorry for making you confusing. I just want to know how this solution can work.  it just move all activity into second dex file. In my case, all test methods(more than 64k) are referenced in one activity. Why second dex file will not complain about more methods in it.  Is this more clearly? thanks your help in advance.

Comment: @mmm2006 Read my linked blogpost once again - it includes all the required info (I believe). In a nutshell, main dex (classes.dex) is important because he's the only one that loaded automatically on application creation. Every class that is not directly or indirectly referenced by Application class can be placed in one of secondary dex files (classes2.dex, classes3.dex, etc).