# Multidex :no class found exception

Tags: android, android-multidex

my app exceeding 64k methods so iam supposed to implement Multidex ,
initially i had problem as "local path doesnt exist" i fixed that problem ,now   gradle generated classes1.dex and classes2.dex ,
but not working in lower than lollipop..it was working fine in lollipop since it has a native support .error says that "<1st activity> is not present in dex path"

after seeing some tutorials they said that have to do a change in 1.gradle 2.application class 3.manifest

i dont have much knowledge about application class ..kindly guide me thanks

note:this is an imported project from eclipse .

kindly check build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
defaultConfig {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    minSdkVersion 15 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
    targetSdkVersion 23


}
dexOptions {
    jumboMode = true

    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
}
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
productFlavors {
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You followed a tutorial that shows how you could add multi-dex support manually **before** Android gradle plugin had support for it. Since v0.14.0, all you need to do is to add:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
     ...
     multiDexEnabled true
}
```

And you can choose one of three options to call the MultiDex code. From [MultiDexApplication documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html):

> Minimal MultiDex capable application. 
>   To use the legacy multidex library there is 3 possibilities:
>   - Declare this class as the application in your AndroidManifest.xml.
>   - Have your Application extends this class.
>   - Have your Application override attachBaseContext starting with
>
> ```
>     protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
>         super.attachBaseContext(base);
>         MultiDex.install(this);
>     }
> ```

Don't forget to remove the `afterEvaluate` block from your build script.

Make sure you've read the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

Comment: @rajsharmashanmugam Try to clean your project and then build again. 
If same build failure occurs, the "too many classes in --main-dex-list" error means that you have way too many dependencies. Try to remove what you don't need. For last resort, check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32753991/32781172#32781172) for a similar issue.